# Making your own drink powders?

Tags: drinks

I love the flavor of crystal light, but it is expensive, and I don't like the artificial sweeteners. I don't think I would mind the drink without the sweeteners, and would like to try to make my own.

I've googled and googled, but I cannot find any talk about what is actually in crystal light or any of the other drink mixes, or how to make your own.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: I just mixed 1/2 tsp of citric acid, 1 tbls of Xylitol and two cups of water to produce something very similar in taste without the strong aftertaste of aspartame

Comment: Get used to the taste of water. It's the cheapest solution.

Comment: I typically drink either water or tea, and have no problem with it. I just like to mix things up every now and again.

Comment: Why does it have to be a powder? It is much easier to cook a sweet concentrated syrup from fruit and sugar, keep it in the fridge, and dilute it for drinks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From Asian supply shops you can often find small packets of powdered fruits. Check the packet but many are made from actual fruit!

I have seen Apple, Cherry, Coconut, Lime, Mango, Pomegranate, Strawberry etc.

Google for powdered fruit and you'll find a variety of online sources

My favourite is Lime powder (99% Lime, made in Malaysia)

Add Aloe Vera powder to make a thickened drink

Add Arrowroot or instant custard powder to make a cloudy "juice"

Add Ascorbic acid powder (Vit. C) as a preservative (be careful not to exceed RDI)

Add Citric acid to make it more citrus like

Add sugar (real or fake) to bulk it out so a simple measure (e.g. one tea spoon) makes a glass of drink

Experiment with the quantities, but you don't need much of anything to get an effective result

Comment: Perfect, powdered fruit was what I was looking for! Can you recommend any websites in specific, or do you always buy local? (I don't have an asian shop that I know of locally)

Comment: @Malfist A quick Google for "powdered fruit natural" yields plenty. The somewhat acidic fruits seem to have the strongest flavours, but it looks like you can even get Banana in the USA?

Answer (score 2):

Kool-Aid, which goes on sale for as low as $0.10 a packet, makes an inexpensive base for home brew drink mixes. To get something drinkable by non-kids, you have to cut the sugar to about 1/4 cup per 2 quarts liquid, or you can mix with Stevia instead. A little citric acid will give the stuff more of a kick, while adding a little KCl/NaCl stock solution yields a nice Gatorade substitute at about $0.08 a bottle.